# php str_replace dynamic url in header.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, str-replace

hey guys,
a little weird question that doesn't actually need to be associated with wordpress.

i want to test a wordpress website on my iPhone. since i'm in the same network, i can simply call my local apache server from my iphone. however since my setup is a bit complicated the website on the iphone has completely wrong links to all its stylesheets and js-files.

anyway, since i'm not really a php person i wonder if it's simply possible to run a php script at the end of my header.php to just replace any **http://mylocaltestdomain.com** by **http://192.168.172.29/mylocaltestdomain.com**

however all the links to stylesheets are generated dynamically. e.g.

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

so again, just so you get it: i wonder if it's possible to replace all dynamic wordpress links (bloginfo('template_directory'...) with some other structure.

is that possible? how?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site isn't live, you could temporarily change the `WordPress address (URL)` value (in Settings -> General) to the server's IP address.